# Radiobutton created dynamically rendered as unchecked in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, dynamic, radio-button

I'm dynamically generating a `radiobutton` in code behind. And setting the checked property to true i.e. `Checked = true` for the `radiobutton`. on page_load the `Radiobutton` is rendered as checked in IE,Firefox but not in Chrome it does render as `Radiobutton` unchecked.

This is my code:

```
var radio = new HtmlInputRadioButton  
{  
ID = id  
};  
placeholder.Controls.Add(radio);  
radio.Name = name;  
radio.Checked = value;
```

what is the fix to make the radiobutton selected on page_load for Chrome?

Comment: What is the value of `value`?

Comment: I'm passing a boolean value true.  radio.checked = true;

Answer (score 0):

I've tested and tested and I can't get Chrome to not have the radio button selected using the following code.

```
var radio = new HtmlInputRadioButton
{
    ID = "testRadio",
    Name = "something",
    Checked = true,
};
phTest.Controls.Add(radio);
```

If you're still having problems you might post your actual code to demonstrate the issue.